# How to get rid of JAXBElement<Integer> in WS client jar generated by clientgen

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, ant, weblogic, jax-ws

I am generating ws clients by following [clientgen](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_ref/anttasks.html#wp1039270) ant task

```
    <clientgen-contact
        wsdl="${wsdl-url-contact}"
        destFile="${output-file-contact}"
        packageName="${packageName}"
        type="JAXWS"
        overwrite="true"
    />
```

But some class in resulting jars have variable names `JAXBElement<Integer>` instead of `Integer`.

How can I avoid this and get `Integer` instead?

---

**Solution**

The solution is to create a binding file as *Paulius Matulionis* says. You can give binding file parameter to clientgen as follows:

```
    <clientgen-contact
        wsdl="${wsdl-url-contact}"
        destFile="${output-file-contact}"
        packageName="${packageName}"
        type="JAXWS"
        overwrite="true"  
    >
        <binding file="${bindingFilePath}"/>
    </clientgen-contact>
```

**Binding.xml full content:**

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" 
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
   <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/> 
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create `JAXB` binding file and include it while generating client. The file should look like this:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Flag `generateElementProperty` set to false and it will prevent generating `JAXBElement<Integer>` instead of `Integer`.